# Steenrod operations on classifying spaces

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory

Steenrod operations can be defined for all finite characteristics $p$. The simplest one, when $p=2$, is the Steenrod square. I wonder if the computation for classifying spaces for classical Lie groups $G$, i.e., the Steenrod operations on $H^*(BG)$, has ever been done. The case for $G = U(n)$ or torus and $p =2$ is probably easy, but I cannot find reference for more general situations.

Comment: Have you looked at the book by Milnor and Stasheff, on characteristic classes?

Comment: You’ll find “Wu formula” and “characteristic class” to be useful search keywords.

Comment: The most complete reference(s) I know of in this regard are the monographs *The topology of Lie groups, I and II* by Mimura and Toda.